# How do I split a string into an array?

Tags: c#, split

I want to split a string into an array. The string is as follows:

> :hello:mr.zoghal:

I would like to split it as follows:

> hello mr.zoghal

I tried ...

```
string[] split = string.Split(new Char[] {':'});
```

and now I want to have:

```
  string  something = hello ;
  string  something1 = mr.zoghal;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: With your latest change, it is no longer clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your original request:

```
string myString = ":hello:mr.zoghal:";
string[] split = myString.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var somethings = split.Select(s => String.Format("something = {0};", s));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", somethings.ToArray()));
```

This will produce

```
something = hello;
something = mr.zoghal;
```

in accordance to your request.

Also, the line

```
string[] split = string.Split(new Char[] {':'});
```

is not legal C#. `String.Split` is an instance-level method whereas your current code is either trying to invoke `Split` on an instance named `string` (not legal as "`string`" is a reserved keyword) or is trying to invoke a static method named `Split` on the class `String` (there is no such method).

Edit: It isn't exactly clear what you are asking. But I think that this will give you what you want:

```
string myString = ":hello:mr.zoghal:";
string[] split = myString.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string something = split[0];
string something1 = split[1];
```

Now you will have

```
something == "hello"
```

and

```
something1 == "mr.zoghal"
```

both evaluate as true. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Is there a reason you do `String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) == false` and not `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)`?

Comment: Personal preference. There are no good reasons other than it is what I prefer because I have overlooked too many "!"s in my days.

Comment: sorry for my bad  spell  over 24 none sleep working on unkn0wn langueage is little hard , ok , yes that is what i want , But i get this error : 

Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\vir-fu\vir-fu\Program.cs 167 30 vir-fu

Comment: @zimzim: Use string[] split = myString.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Answer (score 3):

String myString = ":hello:mr.zoghal:";

```
string[] split = myString.Split(':');

string newString = string.Empty;

foreach(String s in split) {
 newString += "something = " + s + "; ";
}
```

Your output would be:
something = hello; something = mr.zoghal;

Comment: This will produce newString == "something = ; something = hello; something = mr.zoghal; something = ;"

Comment: Good answer, although I'd not pick concatenating a new string as sample.

better go like:

   string something = split[0];
   string something1 = split[1];

I'd say learning about arrays should be a priority here rather than going over string.split semantics.

Comment: @Tigraine: The OP has changed his question to be semantically different from his original question.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier than that. There is already an option.

```
string mystring = ":hello:mr.zoghal:";
string[] split = mystring.Split(new char[] {':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```